# PHP Calling Powershell script not to wait for script completion

Tags: php, powershell, fastcgi

I am calling a power shell command from PHP using shell_exec i don't want PHP to wait till the script completes as i need to kill php once it run the power shell

I am using below code:

```
$abc ="powershellscript.ps1 "   ;   
$abc = shell_exec("PowerShell.exe  -command $abc");
```

I have tried to put > Null or alot > /dev/null & but nothing works

I am using PHP and WINDOWS using FastCGI

Comment: Try the following `PowerShell.exe  -command $abc 2>/dev/null >/dev/null &`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like
`shell_exec("nohup PowerShell.exe  -command $abc 2>&1 &");`

Answer (score 0):

You may consider running PowerShell part using `Start-Job -ScriptBlock { your command}`
This will run the PowerShell command as a background job and will exit immediately.

To be precise:

```
Powershell -nologo -NoProfile -command "Start-Job -FilePath C:\Temp\Sample.ps1"
```